# Android google analytics: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have two android applications using google analytics. I setup it as instruction in this link:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/
But, when I install this two apps, I received error

> INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

I don't use provider with android:authorities

My application tag in manifest as below

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.game.gdx.android.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.game.gdx.android.WebViewActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The authority that is listed in `android:authorities` must be unique. See this link for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth

One last hing to check, make sure in both of your manifests you have same package name is defined. Use this same package name to get the google analytics configuration file.

```
<manifest package="com.your.program" ... >
```

After completing that make sure you uninstall your both apps and install again.

Comment: Hi Caner, as I posted, I don't use provider with android:authorities in my manifest

Comment: Thank Caner, I will check but now I decided remove GA from my app